# Authenticate fiddler with Office 365

Tags: office365, fiddler

How can I configure fiddler to get data from office 365 list? I am trying to run this query:

> https://donsite-3fc9cdc6e06359.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/app1/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Announcements')/?$select=Title

But it's giving me 403, how can I authenticate it?

Answer (score 1):

Please first open Fiddler to capture all the HTTP(S) request, and then open a browser to navigate to your Office 365 tenant. Login to your tenant, and open a list from UI. At this time, Fiddler should have already received lots of HTTP request, pick up of one of them with status 200 into the Fiddler request form, and then change the request URL to your own URL. Keep the header without changes, which should include valid cookie information to authenticate your request.